# What solution choose for app user data storage in a cloud

Tags: azure, google-app-engine, cloud

We want to make possibility in our program for >1mln users to use their data in a cloud. The data sets are small (about 1-2MB) but the main requirement is that we don't want to have access to their data - desktop program should load data from cloud/server and every user should have his own account but we should'nt have access to raw data of users.

I see such possibilities

1. make possible to save ie. in Google Drive through their API

   - pros:

     - every user has data in their account - we dont have access to it
   - cons:

     - not everybody likes google,
     - user has to authorise access for our program to google (can look risky for users)
     - we cannot have our logo in user registering and account process (it is Google window and cannot be changed)
2. crypt all user data with user password and save in our server/Azure/Google Apps

   - pros:

     - even if a hacker would break into server he will not use the user data
   - cons:

     - users must remember their password - if they loose pass they cannot access data (and they use our program once a year so they could have lost it easily)
3. some hybrid of these two aproaches? Any ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evernote provides this functionality, they use method #2.

I have to enter my password every time to decrypt it and if I lose my password, the content cannot be recovered, but they clearly explained the usage/risks.

See if this user experience works for you.

https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/209005547-How-to-encrypt-content-inside-Evernote